# Get multiple values from a web service

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have a webservice, in which the parameter "upload_images" have more than one value. How can i get that values. I am using SBJson. Here is my response

```
{
    "node_title": "thk",
    "category": "Boating",
    "description": "Fg",
    "link": "",
    "nid": "446",
    "post date": "Mon, 11/25/2013 - 07:04",
    "upload_images": "http://prod.kyzook.com/?q=sites/prod.kyzook.com/files/styles/medium/public/2013-11-25%2007%3A03%3A25%20%2B0000.png&itok=WIBTqzbC, http://prod.kyzook.com/?q=sites/prod.kyzook.com/files/styles/medium/public/2013-11-25%2007%3A03%3A58%20%2B0000.png&itok=AhoLUnou"
 }
```

Comment: just take value of "upload_images" in a string and separate that string with "," as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `upload_images` contains a string of comma-separated URLs and you want to extract them.

You can easily achieve this using `NSString`'s method `componentsSeparatedByString`, for instance

```
NSString *uploadImages = response[@"upload_images"];
NSArray *imageURLs = [uploadImages componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

where I assumed `response` to be a `NSDictionary` object holding the parsed response.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the the `"upload_images"` as the `string` and can convert in the `array` using `componentsSeparatedByString:` method

```
NSString *uploadImages = [response objectForKey:@"upload_images"];
NSArray *imageUrlArray = [uploadImages componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```